# Target [App\Http\Requests\Request] is not instantiable when trying to update user

Tags: php, laravel

I've got an EditUsersRequest Request set up for editing users, and in order to make sure email addresses stay unique but ignore the email address of the user being edited (so they don't have to change their email address to something unique every time they get edited), I've got as parameters Request $request in the rules() function. This worked perfectly fine yesterday, and I've made no changes to the code, but now I keep getting the error Target [App\Http\Requests\Request] is not instantiable. when trying to update the user. How can I fix this? I don't understand why it's now not working. Here's the code for the request and the controller:

Request:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use App\Http\Requests\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class EditUserRequest extends Request
{
    public function authorize()
    {
        return Auth::user()->isActive() ? true:false;
    }

    public function messages()
    {
        return [
            'unique'=>'That email address is already registered',
            'regex'=>'Password must contain at least 1 letter and 1 number'
        ];
    }

    public function rules(Request $request)
    {
        return [
            'name'=>'required|min:2|max:50',
            'email'=>'required|email|max:50|unique:users,email,'.$request->get('id'),
            'password'=>'required'
            //'password'=>'required|min:8|regex:/[a-zA-Z][0-9]/' NOT IN USE WHILE IN DE
        ];
    }
}
```

Controller method:

```
public function update(EditUserRequest $request, $id)
    {
        $user = User::findOrFail($id);

        if(trim($request->password) == '') {
            $data = $request->except('password');
        } else {
            $data = $request->all();
            $data['password'] = bcrypt($request->password);
        }

        if($file = $request->file('photo_id')) {
            $name = time().'_'.$file->getClientOriginalName();

            $file->move('images', $name);
            $photo = Photo::create(['path'=>$name]);
            $data['photo_id'] = $photo->id;
        }

        $data['is_active'] = !$request->is_active ? 0:1;

        $message = $user->update($data) ? "User {$user->name} has been updated": "Unable to update user {$user->name}";

        Session::flash('updated', $message);

        return redirect('/admin/users');
    }
```

Comment: Have you got `use App\Http\Requests\EditUserRequest` in the controller?

Comment: Version of laravel?

Comment: using `$this->segment(3)` was a great idea. https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Http/Request.html I don't see any better way myself

Comment: I actually ended up using `$this->route('users')` to make it a little more dynamic (:

Comment: You should answer your question, you got my upvote~ :)

Answer (score 3):

use

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```

Instead of

```
use App\Http\Requests\Request;
```

You can also check here : https://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Http/Request.html

Comment: Tried that and it didn't throw any errors, but it didn't actually update the user for some reason

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
use Request;
```

Instead of

```
use App\Http\Requests\Request;
```

Answer (score 0):

`$this->route('users')` can be used to obtain the user id. Either that or `$this->segment(3)` will work properly. Using route is just a little more dynamic.